# set webpage content to default width, but also resizable

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a completely responsive website, but I need the pages to have a default width of 960px. The structure I have is as follows:

```
<div id="container">
<table id="content">
all the content is here
</table>
</div>
```

now I want the table to be a default width of 960px, but I want it to be able to re-size as well, just like its width and height were auto and its position relative. These are the styles I have now

```
#container{
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
}
#content{
width: 960px;
height: auto;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
-mox-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}
```

If I set the #content width to auto, then the webpage is fully responsive but has no default width. If I set it to 960px like I have above, the entire webpage has a fixed width. I have been struggling with this for quite a while, any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: width:100% or percent rather than 100%

Comment: some kind look like this [sample](http://dev.flowinteractive.com.au/belleisle/) or not? if you have `screen width:1920px` then the layout stay `960px` but if the `screen width` smaller `1000px or 720px` then the layout make flexible. is that what you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#content{
    max-width: 960px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
    -mox-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.7);
}
```

Note that I've set 960 as the `max-width`, but then set the `width` to 100%. This would make the website responsive, but still have the width to be 960px (unless the browser size is smaller than this).

Answer (score 2):

I see that albertxing already gave you an awsome answer, but I wanna recommend you to get to know [Ethan Marcotte](http://alistapart.com/author/emarcotte)  - the Godfather of responsive webdesign (rwd).

He has composed some great articles at Alistapart that you may want to begin with. Great stuff!

Comment: Glad you liked it. It helped me alot on my journey to become a web developer.